# how to include a module from another file

Tags: rust

I created a Cargo project. My project tree looks like this:

```
├── src
    ├── main.rs
    ├── animal.rs
    └── human.rs
```

**animal.rs**

```
use crate::human::Job;
pub struct Animal {
    id: u8,
    job: Job,
}
impl Animal {
    pub fn new(i: u8, j: Job) -> Animal {
        Animal {id:i, job:j}
    }
}
```

**human.rs**

```
pub struct Human {
    id: u8,
    job: Job,
}
pub enum Job {
    Builder,
    Magician,
}
impl Human {
    pub fn new(i: u8, j: Job) -> Human {
        Human {id: i, job: j}
    }
}
```

When I compile it, it complains

```
$ cargo run
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `human` in the crate root
 --> src/animal.rs:4:17
  |
4 |     job: crate::human::Job,
  |                 ^^^^^ could not find `human` in the crate root
```

It gets compiled if I add "mod human;" in main.rs. What is the right way to include one module from another file in the same project?

Comment: Does your main.rs contain a module declaration for `human`? In rust modules are not derived from the file structure and must be declared explicitly.

Comment: main.rs does not contain a module declaration for human.

Answer (score 2):

The default package structure `cargo` expects is described here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html

Therefore, you would expect to have the following files:

```
└── src
    ├── main.rs
    ├── lib.rs
    ├── animal.rs
    └── human.rs
```

And `lib.rs` should contain

```rust
mod animal;
mod human;
```

The `main.rs` is an executable that would use the crate as if the library was a dependency:

```
use <crate_name>::human::Job;

fn main() {
  // do whatever with `Job`
}
```

`crate_name` here would be the name of the crate in `Cargo.toml`.

Although technically nothing prevents you from declaring the modules inside `main.rs` like so:

```
mod animal;
mod human;

fn main() {
  // use `human::Job`
}
```

Comment: I must note that `lib.rs` is optional in this case

Comment: Thank you.  What is the right <crate_name> in my case? I needed to put "crate" to get it compiled. Does it mean the root of the project tree?

Comment: @Jihyun in case where you have both `lib.rs` and `main.rs` there are technically two crates: One with `main` as it's root, another with `lib`. To refer to items from `lib` crate in `main` crate you need to use `your_crate_name`.

Comment: Meanwhile the `crate` keyword always refers to the *current* crate.